# How can I relocate the values of one column into many different columns under different names?

Tags: r, dataframe, variables

Let's say I have this df (but with thousand of IDs and tens of treatments)

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                treatment = c('AB','CD','EF','AB','CD','GH','IM','LN') )
```

I wish to obtain the following output

```
   ID treatment_1 treatment_2 treatment_3 treatment_4 treatment_5
1  1          AB          CD          EF        <NA>        <NA>
2  2          AB          CD          GH          IM          LN
```

What I don't want

```
    ID   .by Treatment_1 Treatment_2 Treatment_3 Treatment_4 Treatment_5 Treatment_6 Treatment_7 Treatment_8
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
1     1     1 AB          CD          EF          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA         
2     2     2 NA          NA          NA          AB          CD          GH          IM          LN
```

Comment: `library(dplyr); library(tidyr); df %>%  mutate(rown = row_number(), .by = ID) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "rown", values_from = "treatment", names_prefix = "Treatment_")`

Comment: Switching from long to wide format is probably going to make your analysis more difficult here. Are you _sure_ you need to switch to that format? Might you even be better with a column for each treatment, indicating whether the subject got that treatment? Something like `table(ID = df$ID, treatment = df$treatment) == 1`?

Comment: unfortunately no it is not gonna work that way because there are like a hundred different categories of my variable

Comment: @Maël it is still not what I am looking for because the output of your function is not exactly the output i am looking for

Comment: This question shouldn’t be closed because it’s not like the other question

Comment: How is the output different? The code Mael provided produces output that looks to me like your desired output.

Comment: I've added three other duplicate links that are essentially the same: create a row number by group, and pivot. That's why this is a duplicate

Comment: no it is not because it considers each treatment as a different column. What I want is that patient 1 treatment 1 is AB and patient 2 Treatment 1 is AB. In the code of  
Maël : patient 1 treatment 1 is AB and patient 2 Treatment 1 is NA

Comment: You should update `dplyr` and try again.  The code is correct but your version of `dplyr` is out of date and doesn't recognise the `.by` argument to do grouped calculations. Or use the older `group_by()` function.

Comment: I have the 1.0.10 version. I tried using the argument group_by and the function group_by, and still did not work. anyway will see when I have an updated version hopefully will work thanks all of you.

Comment: I finally found a solution to the problem since I was not able to update the package. It would be : ```df%>%group_by(ID)%>%mutate(rown = row_number())%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "rown", values_from = "treatment", names_prefix = "Treatment_")```